# How to convert application/binary data to plain data in linux

Tags: linux, binary, echo

One of the my server gives me the data with  **Content-Type: application/binary** , i.e data that i am getting looks like some elien data, now i need to convert that data into plain data, i am not getting way to how to do that. I am doing this everything using linux commandline.

After googling, i got one way, as per that site says, i need to delete first 10 char and last 8 char from my data and then use gunzip with that, then i will get the original data, but when i am trying to delete that much characters, as it is binary output, it cuts more than that or less than 10+8 characters. Actually Echo is not able to print data properly. So, please anyone know how to handle binary data, please help me out.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what format binary data your server is spitting out ?

Comment: Sorry, but it is somewhat confidential, so i cant give the url from where i am getting that, please if you have any experience with binary data then please help me out

Comment: Binary data could be anything - could be an image, a zip file, an exe. You need to know what it is - it may not even convert to text!

Comment: Ya its a zip data, i m sure about that, sorry i forget to mention that

Comment: @downvoter, why u have downvoted it, this is the actual problem i m getting, I am not getting why have you done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, you have binary data and you want to delete the first ten bytes, the last eight bytes, and then gunzip it.  To do that, run from the command line:

```
tail -c +11 binary.in | head -c -8 | gunzip >original.out
```

where you should replace "binary.in" with the name of the file that you got from your server.  The output that you want ends up in a file named "original.out".

There are three things going on in that line.  First "tail -c +11 binary.in" takes your binary file and outputs all but the first 10 bytes.  Second, "head -c -8" reads from the output of the tail command and writes all but the last eight bytes.  Third, "gunzip >original.out" reads from the output of the head command, unzips it, and sends the result to a the file "original.out".  The vertical bars "|" connect the standard output of one command to the standard input of the next.